# Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function on map returned array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is how I am getting all the id's of div's inside a parent

```
 var ids = $('#layers div').map(function(index) {
                return $(this).attr('id'); 
           });
```

However when  I do

```
ids.reverse();
```

To my surprise it showing an error (`Uncaught TypeError: ids.reverse is not a function`) although reverse is native javascript arrays function.

So I quickly suspected that it is not an array object and looked into [Jquery map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) functions docs and it says

> Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `.get()` along with [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get native array.

> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.

```
var ids = $('#layers div').map(function(index) {
    return $(this).attr('id'); 
}).get();
```

```js
var ids = $('div').map(function(index) {
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();

console.log(ids.reverse());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```